# How do we connect video streaming of different tokens generated for a single session using openTok

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

You can see What I'm trying to do.

**I want to Connect all the users in a session by providing them separate token under a 
sessionId, so that they can view each other's streaming. But users can see only their 
straming. I just need to allocate div on my page for each user with a token connected to any 
particular sessionId.**

This is the code using which users can see their streaming only

```
    <script src="http://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.0/js/TB.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.0/js/TB.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var publisher;
    var session;

    var apiKey = "44686132";


    var sessionId = "1_MX40NDY4NjEzMn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1hciAxOSAyMDo1ODozNyBQRFQgMjAxNH4wLjAzMTA3MTAwN34";
    var token = document.getElementById("<%= hdn1.ClientID %>").value;


    publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey);

    session = TB.initSession(sessionId);

    session.connect(apiKey, token);
    session.addEventListener("sessionConnected",
                           sessionConnectedHandler);


    session.addEventListener("streamCreated",
                           streamCreatedHandler);


    function sessionConnectedHandler(event) {
        alert("sessionConnectedHandler");


        subscribeToStreams(event.streams);
        session.publish(publisher);

    }
        function subscribeToStreams(streams) {

                if (stream.connection.connectionId
               != session.connection.connectionId) {
                    //var streams = event.streams;
                    for (var i = 0; i < streams.length; i++) {
                        var stream = streams[i];

                        var newDivId = "streams" + stream[i].streamId;
                        var newDiv = $('<div />', { id: newDivId });
                        $('body').append(newDiv);
                        if (stream.connection.connectionId
               != session.connection.connectionId) {
                            session.subscribe(stream[i], newDivId);
                        }

                }
            }
        }
        function streamCreatedHandler(event) {
            subscribeToStreams(event.streams);

        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your session and publisher object are outside the scope of the other methods and your are probably getting errors. If you define session and publisher variables outside your method a() everything will work as expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var session, publisher;

  function sessionConnectedHandler(event)...
  ...
```

Comment: I've tried it that way also, but only self streaming is seen...What do I do

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.0/js/TB.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.0/js/TB.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var publisher;
var session;

var apiKey = "44686132";


var sessionId = "1_MX40NDY4NjEzMn4xMjcuMC4wLjF-V2VkIE1hciAxOSAyMDo1ODozNyBQRFQgMjAxNH4wLjAzMTA3MTAwN34";

var token = document.getElementById("<%= hdn1.ClientID %>").value;


publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey);

session = TB.initSession(apiKey,sessionId);
  $.post('generate token url', data)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    session.connect(data.token, function (error) {
                        if (error) 
                        {

                        }
                        });
                    });

session.addEventListener("sessionConnected",
                       sessionConnectedHandler);


session.addEventListener("streamCreated",
                       streamCreatedHandler);


function sessionConnectedHandler(event) {
    alert("sessionConnectedHandler");


    subscribeToStreams(event.streams);
    session.publish(publisher);

}
    function subscribeToStreams(streams) {

            if (stream.connection.connectionId
           != session.connection.connectionId) {
                //var streams = event.streams;
                for (var i = 0; i < streams.length; i++) {
                    var stream = streams[i];

                    var newDivId = "streams" + stream[i].streamId;
                    var newDiv = $('<div />', { id: newDivId });
                    $('body').append(newDiv);
                    if (stream.connection.connectionId
           != session.connection.connectionId) {
                        session.subscribe(stream[i], newDivId);
                    }

            }
        }
    }
    function streamCreatedHandler(event) {
        subscribeToStreams(event.streams);

    }
```

generate token every time new when u want to connect to singal session with diffrent token.

this code will help u.